# require_once elimina "\" de la ruta

Tags: php

Estoy intentando acceder al archivo "functions_user" de phpbb3 desde mi página para realizar inserción de usuarios pero `require_once` me elimina uno de los slash (`\`) y no reconoce el directorio.
Este es el código que utilizo para abrirlo

```
define('ROOT', 'C:\AppServ\www\Ok\Foro\');
require_once(ROOT . "includes\functions_user.php");
```

He intentado añadir un `\` antes del "include" pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> **Warning**:  require_once(C:\AppServ\www\Ok\Foro\includesunctions_user.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in **C:\AppServ\www\Ok\tasks\archivo.php** on line **5**

Como se puede ver, la línea de la rúta elimina el carácter y lo remplaza. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: Y cual es la estructura de tu proyecto ?

Comment: Apenas llamar al archivo me da ese error, pues está en las primeras líneas, si no se abre ese archivo, no puede continuar. ¿Crees necesario que añada la estructura?

Comment: Al definir `ROOT` pusiste un \ de más al final, ¿no será eso lo que te está dando problemas? Defínelo así:  **`define('ROOT', 'C:\AppServ\www\Ok\Foro\');`**

Comment: A. Cedano, la he editado de mil formas y sigue igual. Al final conseguí acceder al archivo pero no ejecuta la función. No sé si eliminar esta pregunta y hacer otra o añadir un update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando este comando:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(ROOT . '\requireone\includes\functions_user.php');
```

1) Verifica hasta donde te lleva el `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` y completas la ruta dentro del require_once como yo hice en el ejemplo: \requireone\includes\functions_user.php'

2) Debes cambiar la ruta de `require_once()` por la que tienes que completar para llegar al archivo **functions_user.php**